# How to output the E function, XOR process and F process for each round in DES?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, output, des

```
import java.util.*; 

class Main { 
    private static class DES { 
        // CONSTANTS
```

// Initial Permutation Table

```
        int[] IP = { 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 
                    10, 2, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 
                    12, 4, 62, 54, 46, 38, 
                    30, 22, 14, 6, 64, 56, 
                    48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 
                    57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 
                    9, 1, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 
                    19, 11, 3, 61, 53, 45, 
                    37, 29, 21, 13, 5, 63, 55, 
                    47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7 };
```

// Inverse Initial Permutation Table

```
        int[] IP1 = { 40, 8, 48, 16, 56, 24, 64, 
                    32, 39, 7, 47, 15, 55, 
                    23, 63, 31, 38, 6, 46, 
                    14, 54, 22, 62, 30, 37, 
                    5, 45, 13, 53, 21, 61, 
                    29, 36, 4, 44, 12, 52, 
                    20, 60, 28, 35, 3, 43, 
                    11, 51, 19, 59, 27, 34, 
                    2, 42, 10, 50, 18, 58, 
                    26, 33, 1, 41, 9, 49, 
                    17, 57, 25 };
```

// first key-Permutation Table

```
        int[] PC1 = { 57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 
                    17, 9, 1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 
                    18, 10, 2, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 
                    19, 11, 3, 60, 52, 44, 36, 63, 
                    55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7, 62, 
                    54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6, 61, 
                    53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5, 28, 
                    20, 12, 4 };
```

// second key-Permutation Table

```
        int[] PC2 = { 14, 17, 11, 24, 1, 5, 3, 
                    28, 15, 6, 21, 10, 23, 19, 12, 
                    4, 26, 8, 16, 7, 27, 20, 13, 2, 
                    41, 52, 31, 37, 47, 55, 30, 40, 
                    51, 45, 33, 48, 44, 49, 39, 56, 
                    34, 53, 46, 42, 50, 36, 29, 32 };
```

// Expansion D-box Table

```
        int[] EP = { 32, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
                    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10, 
                    11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                    16, 17, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                    21, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
                    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 28, 
                    29, 30, 31, 32, 1 };
```

// Straight Permutation Table

```
        int[] P = { 16, 7, 20, 21, 29, 12, 28, 
                    17, 1, 15, 23, 26, 5, 18, 
                    31, 10, 2, 8, 24, 14, 32, 
                    27, 3, 9, 19, 13, 30, 6, 
                    22, 11, 4, 25 };
```

// S-box Table

```
        int[][][] sbox = { 
            { { 14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7 }, 
            { 0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8 }, 
            { 4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0 }, 
            { 15, 12, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, 11, 3, 14, 10, 0, 6, 13 } }, 

            { { 15, 1, 8, 14, 6, 11, 3, 4, 9, 7, 2, 13, 12, 0, 5, 10 }, 
            { 3, 13, 4, 7, 15, 2, 8, 14, 12, 0, 1, 10, 6, 9, 11, 5 }, 
            { 0, 14, 7, 11, 10, 4, 13, 1, 5, 8, 12, 6, 9, 3, 2, 15 }, 
            { 13, 8, 10, 1, 3, 15, 4, 2, 11, 6, 7, 12, 0, 5, 14, 9 } }, 
            { { 10, 0, 9, 14, 6, 3, 15, 5, 1, 13, 12, 7, 11, 4, 2, 8 }, 
            { 13, 7, 0, 9, 3, 4, 6, 10, 2, 8, 5, 14, 12, 11, 15, 1 }, 
            { 13, 6, 4, 9, 8, 15, 3, 0, 11, 1, 2, 12, 5, 10, 14, 7 }, 
            { 1, 10, 13, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 15, 14, 3, 11, 5, 2, 12 } }, 
            { { 7, 13, 14, 3, 0, 6, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8, 5, 11, 12, 4, 15 }, 
            { 13, 8, 11, 5, 6, 15, 0, 3, 4, 7, 2, 12, 1, 10, 14, 9 }, 
            { 10, 6, 9, 0, 12, 11, 7, 13, 15, 1, 3, 14, 5, 2, 8, 4 }, 
            { 3, 15, 0, 6, 10, 1, 13, 8, 9, 4, 5, 11, 12, 7, 2, 14 } }, 
            { { 2, 12, 4, 1, 7, 10, 11, 6, 8, 5, 3, 15, 13, 0, 14, 9 }, 
            { 14, 11, 2, 12, 4, 7, 13, 1, 5, 0, 15, 10, 3, 9, 8, 6 }, 
            { 4, 2, 1, 11, 10, 13, 7, 8, 15, 9, 12, 5, 6, 3, 0, 14 }, 
            { 11, 8, 12, 7, 1, 14, 2, 13, 6, 15, 0, 9, 10, 4, 5, 3 } }, 
            { { 12, 1, 10, 15, 9, 2, 6, 8, 0, 13, 3, 4, 14, 7, 5, 11 }, 
            { 10, 15, 4, 2, 7, 12, 9, 5, 6, 1, 13, 14, 0, 11, 3, 8 }, 
            { 9, 14, 15, 5, 2, 8, 12, 3, 7, 0, 4, 10, 1, 13, 11, 6 }, 
            { 4, 3, 2, 12, 9, 5, 15, 10, 11, 14, 1, 7, 6, 0, 8, 13 } }, 
            { { 4, 11, 2, 14, 15, 0, 8, 13, 3, 12, 9, 7, 5, 10, 6, 1 }, 
            { 13, 0, 11, 7, 4, 9, 1, 10, 14, 3, 5, 12, 2, 15, 8, 6 }, 
            { 1, 4, 11, 13, 12, 3, 7, 14, 10, 15, 6, 8, 0, 5, 9, 2 }, 
            { 6, 11, 13, 8, 1, 4, 10, 7, 9, 5, 0, 15, 14, 2, 3, 12 } }, 
            { { 13, 2, 8, 4, 6, 15, 11, 1, 10, 9, 3, 14, 5, 0, 12, 7 }, 
            { 1, 15, 13, 8, 10, 3, 7, 4, 12, 5, 6, 11, 0, 14, 9, 2 }, 
            { 7, 11, 4, 1, 9, 12, 14, 2, 0, 6, 10, 13, 15, 3, 5, 8 }, 
            { 2, 1, 14, 7, 4, 10, 8, 13, 15, 12, 9, 0, 3, 5, 6, 11 } } 
        }; 
        int[] shiftBits = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                            1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
```

// hexadecimal to binary conversion

```
        String hextoBin(String input) 
        { 
            int n = input.length() * 4; 
            input = Long.toBinaryString( 
                Long.parseUnsignedLong(input, 16)); 
            while (input.length() < n) 
                input = "0" + input; 
            return input; 
        }
```

// binary to hexadecimal conversion

```
        String binToHex(String input) 
        { 
            int n = (int)input.length() / 4; 
            input = Long.toHexString( 
                Long.parseUnsignedLong(input, 2)); 
            while (input.length() < n) 
                input = "0" + input; 
            return input; 
        }
```

// per-mutate input hexadecimal
// according to specified sequence

```
        String permutation(int[] sequence, String input) 
        { 
            String output = ""; 
            input = hextoBin(input); 
            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) 
                output += input.charAt(sequence[i] - 1); 
            output = binToHex(output); 
            return output; 
        }
```

// xor 2 hexadecimal strings

```
        String xor(String a, String b) 
        { 
            // hexadecimal to decimal(base 10) 
            long t_a = Long.parseUnsignedLong(a, 16); 
            // hexadecimal to decimal(base 10) 
            long t_b = Long.parseUnsignedLong(b, 16); 
            // xor 
            t_a = t_a ^ t_b; 
            // decimal to hexadecimal 
            a = Long.toHexString(t_a); 
            // prepend 0's to maintain length 
            while (a.length() < b.length()) 
                a = "0" + a; 
            return a; 
        }
```

// left Circular Shifting bits

```
        String leftCircularShift(String input, int numBits) 
        { 
            int n = input.length() * 4; 
            int perm[] = new int[n]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
                perm[i] = (i + 2); 
            perm[n - 1] = 1; 
            while (numBits-- > 0) 
                input = permutation(perm, input); 
            return input; 
        }
```

// preparing 16 keys for 16 rounds

```
        String[] getKeys(String key) 
        { 
            String keys[] = new String[16]; 
            // first key permutation 
            key = permutation(PC1, key); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
                key = leftCircularShift( 
                        key.substring(0, 7), shiftBits[i]) 
                    + leftCircularShift(key.substring(7, 14), 
                                        shiftBits[i]); 
                // second key permutation 
                keys[i] = permutation(PC2, key); 
            } 
            return keys; 
        }
```

// s-box lookup

```
        String sBox(String input) 
        { 
            String output = ""; 
            input = hextoBin(input); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 48; i += 6) { 
                String temp = input.substring(i, i + 6); 
                int num = i / 6; 
                int row = Integer.parseInt( 
                    temp.charAt(0) + "" + temp.charAt(5), 2); 
                int col = Integer.parseInt( 
                    temp.substring(1, 5), 2); 
                output += Integer.toHexString( 
                    sbox[num][row][col]); 
            } 
            return output; 
        } 

        String round(String input, String key, int num) 
        { 
            // fk 
            String left = input.substring(0, 8); 
            String temp = input.substring(8, 16); 
            String right = temp; 
            // Expansion permutation 
            temp = permutation(EP, temp); 
            // xor temp and round key 
            temp = xor(temp, key); 
            // lookup in s-box table 
            temp = sBox(temp); 
            // Straight D-box 
            temp = permutation(P, temp); 
            // xor 
            left = xor(left, temp); 
            System.out.println("Round "
                            + (num + 1) + " "
                            + right.toUpperCase() 
                            + " " + left.toUpperCase() + " "
                            + key.toUpperCase()); 

            // swapper 
            return right + left; 
        } 

        String encrypt(String plainText, String key) 
        { 
            int i; 
            // get round keys 
            String keys[] = getKeys(key); 

            // initial permutation 
            plainText = permutation(IP, plainText); 
            System.out.println( 
                "After initial permutation: "
                + plainText.toUpperCase()); 
            System.out.println( 
                "After splitting: L0="
                + plainText.substring(0, 8).toUpperCase() 
                + " R0="
                + plainText.substring(8, 16).toUpperCase() + "\n"); 

            // 16 rounds 
            for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
                plainText = round(plainText, keys[i], i); 
            } 

            // 32-bit swap 
            plainText = plainText.substring(8, 16) 
                        + plainText.substring(0, 8); 

            // final permutation 
            plainText = permutation(IP1, plainText); 
            return plainText; 
        } 

        
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String text = "0123456789ABCDEF"; 
        String key = "133457799BBCDFF1"; 

        DES cipher = new DES(); 
        System.out.println("Encryption:\n"); 
        text = cipher.encrypt(text, key); 
        System.out.println( 
            "\nCipher Text: " + text.toUpperCase() + "\n"); 
        
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the inner working of AES consists of 32 bit machine words, i.e. integers in Java. As you need more than one, they are usually in arrays. AES implementations themselves should contain precisely zero instances of String; those are only required to print out the (inner) state for debugging, but even then you'd use a separate class or static method to print them out.

Remember, modern ciphers such as block ciphers operate on binary, not text (strings).

Comment: The OP presents Digital Encryption Standard Digital Encryption Algorithm permutations and S Boxes. The E Permutation (EP) for instance expands a 32 bit value to 48. A reader might surmise the question is addressed to determining where the OP's code goes wrong by comparing added outputs to say Eugene Styer's [JavaScript DES Exampe](http://styere.xyz/JS-DES.html) expanded output potentially after removing the readonly attributes from key and keyb to allow arbitrary  keys.

Comment: That's a rather different direction for an answer, feel free to add an answer.